# How to set ttk.Button background?

Tags: python, image, tkinter, button, ttk

Does anyone have a good idea how to change the background of the `ttk.Button`? I uploaded an image that describes my issue — background is around the image of the button.

```
if is_on == False:
    is_on = True
    self.__data_collection.update(Bundle=True)
    photo = Image.Tk = PhotoImage(file=r"btn-on.png")
    ttk.Button(image = photo, command=self.__swtich).place(x=230, y=390)
else:
    is_on = False
    self.__data_collection.update(Bundle=False)
    photo = Image.Tk = PhotoImage(file=r"btn-off.png")
    ttk.Button(image = photo, command=self.__swtich).place(x=230, y=390)
print(self.__data_collection)
```

Image:

[image: sample display]

Comment: You need to provide more context to your question — a runnable [mre] would be nice. Also mention what OS you're using.

Comment: I'm using MacOS